# Rails 3 - routing

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't know how to make a link_to because I'dont have a nouveau_message_path in rake routes

rake routes :

```
      GET    /nouveau_message/.:id          {:action=>"nouveau_message", :controller=>"messages"}
```

routes.rb :

```
controller :messages do
   get 'nouveau_message/.:id' => :nouveau_message
end
```

What is the best way to make a link_to to nouveau_message from another view ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rake task really nice to let you know all about your routes' names.

```
rake routes
```

You will be able to see all your routes and their targets.

Anyway your routes should be something like

```
link_to 'Nouveau', nouveau_message_message_path(:id => YOURID)
```

But check with rake routes ;)

Hope this will help you !

EDIT : excuse me, for my previous answer.

Add this to your routes.rb

```
get 'nouveau_message/.:id' => :nouveau_message, :as => 'nouveau_message'
```

:as allows you to name your route !

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't have nouveau_message_message_path,

 I 've use rake routes (see my post) : I have blank instead of a path helper in rake routes.

Comment: Excuse me, I hadn't see you had used rake routes !
Simply add this into your route file.
get 'nouveau_message/.:id' => :nouveau_message, :as => 'nouveau_message'